# How to make Okular open in predefined screen?

Tags: okular

I hope you can help me in this really painful problem.

When I open several pdf from firefox, Okular *always* appears exactly where I am currently working (trying to open new pdfs). This behavior is really annoying as I am forced to put the newly opened pdfs to the right side of the screen before continuing with my work.

I think it be really helpful to make Okular open either on a certain side (left oder right) of the active screen or in another (inactive) screen. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I knew that Compiz can be configured to do that via CCSM, [seems like KWin can do that too](http://userbase.kde.org/KWin/en#You_want_an_application_to_launch_in_a_specific_size_and_position_every_time), even better.